# style xls using XLSX package

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx

I have written some code to add styling to my XLS file, but it is not functioning as expected.

here is my code

```
import * as xlsx from 'xlsx'

const workbook = xlsx.utils.book_new()
const worksheet = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(result, { skipHeader: true, cellStyles: true })

// Define a new style object for center-aligned text
const centerStyle = {
    alignment: {
        vertical: "center",
        horizontal: "center"
    }
};

// Add the style to the styles array in the worksheet
worksheet["styles"].push(centerStyle);
xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, 'EventTickets')
const base64Response = await xlsx.write(workbook, { bookType: extension, type: 'base64', cellStyles: true })
```

i also tried this solution but didn't work as well

```
ws["A1"].s = { alignment: { v: "center", h: "center" } };
```

I'm expecting to have centered text in a specific cell or for all the cells in the xlsx.

Comment: I have the same problem. Please help if there is a way to handle this issue. Thanks!